# GKE auto upgrade is creating new instance template instead of existing template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-instance-template

My GKE cluster is using node pool which contains 1 instance group and 3 nodes. For my nodes, I have a custom instance template.

For my cluster, I have also enabled Auto-upgrade and Auto-repair.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades?_ga=2.122074699.-1778766741.1612187615

Recently, I noticed that GKE upgraded my nodes automatically to a new version but instead of using my custom instance template, it created a new template and used it. Due to it, I lost my custom changes.

My question is
1- Why GKE created a new instance template instead of using the old one?
2- If a new template has to be created then how can I bring my custom changes to the new template automatically?

Thanks

Comment: It would be best to be in touch with the [Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact) so they can further inspect your project